# Trying to break a string up and reverse it

Tags: python, string, split, reverse

I am trying to code a program which will ask for a person's full name (first, middle, last) and will print (last, middle, tsrif). Like print their name backwards, but the letters are backwards only on their first name. I can't figure out how to flip the order of the words without flipping their letters. Any help?

My code so far:

```
import sys
str = raw_input("first middle last")

str.split( );
```

Comment: 1. Don't name variable as `str` 2. `str.split` is not inplace, you will have to store it in another variable

Comment: Thanks for your tip! I started programming today and I am grateful for any tips.

Answer (score 1):

The `str.split()` function returns the list, it doesn't modify it in place. So you want :

```
split_up = str.split()
```

(obviously `split_up` is an arbitrary name, the point is that it's a list)

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> my_string = raw_input('?: ').split()
?: first middle last
>>> new_string = ' '.join(my_string[:0:-1] + [my_string[0][::-1]])
>>> new_string
'last middle tsrif'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> s = 'first middle last'
>>> L = s.split()
>>> L[0] = L[0][::-1]
>>> L
['tsrif', 'middle', 'last']
>>> print L[::-1]
['last', 'middle', 'tsrif']
```

Answer (score 1):

Reverse the list at first. Then reverse the last string in list

```
my_list = string.split()
my_list = list(reversed(my_list))
my_list[2] = my_list[2][::-1]
print my_list
```

Don't use **str** as variable.

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
import sys
str = "first middle last";
allWords = str.split(" ");
length = len(allWords)
for index in range(length-1):
    print(allWords[length-index-1],end=" ")
print((allWords[0])[::-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
input_name = "first middle last" # whatever your input is: using as example here
split_name = input_name.split()
desired_output = [split_name [2], split_name [1], split_name [0][::-1]]

>>> desired_output
 ['last', 'middle', 'tsrif']

>>> ' '.join(desired_output)
'last middle tsrif'

>>> ', '.join(desired_output)
'last, middle, tsrif'
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you have a variable `s` which you've gotten from the user.  If you want to split that up into individual words, you use `.split()` and save the result

```
s = "john henry smith"
parts = s.split() # ['john', 'henry', 'smith']
```

now, to reverse these words, you can use the built in function `reversed` and convert the result to a list

```
rev_parts = list(reversed(parts))  # ['smith', 'henry', 'john']
```

Finally you want to reverse just the last element of `rev_parts`, you can use a `-1` index to indicate the last element in the list.  What you want to do is overwrite the existing element.  We can use `reversed` again here, but we'll also need to use a `join` to tell it to but all the characters back together after

```
rev_name = ''.join(reversed(rev_parts[-1])) # 'nhoj'
rev_parts[-1] = rev_name # overwrite 'john'
```

Now you have a list of what you want.  If you want to put them all back together separated by spaces, use another `join`

```
result = ' '.join(rev_parts)
```

You can eliminate various intermediate variables and steps here as you feel comfortable.

---

An alternative to using `reversed` is to use the slice syntax `[::-1]` which says, from the end to the beginning, back one character at a time.  In that case you'd have

```
rev_parts = parts[::-1]
rev_parts[-1] = rev_parts[-1][::-1]
```